# How to update noip DDNS while wireguard VPN is running?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, wireguard, dynamic-dns

I have a debian router that gives my entire house VPN access, it connects to the server that is in my parent's home in another city with wireguard. I need to do this because of firewall issues. However I want to SSH back into my debian router while I'm outside.

The Debian router is directly connected to a Asus Router which is then connected to the ISP's gateway (router modem combo).

I've tried creating a network namespace to run my ddns update, but I can't get any network access on it. I've tried to run a cron job that disables my VPN and updates, but that is not

The issue is that the no-ip DDNS client, updates with the IP address of my parent's home (which makes sense).
How do I update my DDNS while running a VPN? Are there any other easy way, besides a cron job that turns off my VPN and runs the DDNS update?

Update: My network namespace config

```
#!/bin/bash
NS="nsx"
IF_MAIN="br0"
IF_NS="br0_ns"
IP="192.168.10.2/24"
GATEWAY="192.168.1.1"

ip netns del "$NS"
ip netns add "$NS"
ip link add link "$IF_MAIN" "$IF_NS" netns "$NS" type ipvlan mode l2
ip -n "$NS" link set dev lo up
ip -n "$NS" link set "$IF_NS" up
ip -n "$NS" addr add "$IP" dev "$IF_NS"
ip -n "$NS" route add default via "$GATEWAY" dev "$IF_NS"
```

Comment: Just checking: when there's no VPN, your ISP (ie: not doing CG-NAT) + ISP's router + Asus router all are configured with cascading forwarding rules (I assume even Asus is doing NAT unless told otherwise) toward your Debian router, so it is reachable from Internet when you know your current home public IP address?

Comment: Anyway, can you describe (with application used, interfaces, addresses etc.) how is your DDNS setup done? Any configuration file to share (you can obfuscate secrets. If you obfuscate a public IP address, please use [RFC 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737.html#section-3) ).

Comment: @A.B That is correct.
For my DDNS i use No-ip and run `/usr/bin/noip-duc -g <DDNS domain> -u <user> -p <key>`